# PHP Array Errors

Tags: php, jquery, json

Still trying to figure out php...

I had some php working:

```
<? php
    $returnstr = "";

    //get some info... 
    $returnstr += "title ".$that_info;

    //do some stuff...
    $returnstr += "notes ".$did_stuff;

    echo $returnstr;
?>
```

This was in a single file when testing and worked fine.

Now, tests look good, move php code into its own file and created .js file with function:

```
function get_aint_id(aint_nr)
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'get_ta_top_row.php',
        data: {functionname: 'get_aint_id', arguments: [aint_nr]}, 
        success: function(data) 
        {
            document.getElementById("notify").innerHTML = data;
        },
        error: function(data)
        {
                    return 0;
        }
    });
}
```

Stopped working, always returned 0.

Modified PHP code to (echo values directly instead of building string):

```
<? php
    //get some info... 
    exho "title ".$that_info;

    //do some stuff...
    echo "notes ".$did_stuff;
?>
```

Works again!

But the problem now is that I need to return some values (status (sucess/error), an ID, some info text, etc...).

After some searching, it seemed that json seemed the best option. So I modified the .php to:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
    $function = $_POST['functionname'];

    switch($function)
    {
        case "get_aint_id":
        {
            $aint_nr = "%".$_POST['arguments'][0];
            get_aint_id($aint_nr);
            break;
        }
    }

    function get_aint_id($aint_nr)
    {
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        // Configure connection params
        $response_array = array();

        // Connect to DB
        $conn = odbc_connect( $connect_string, $db_user, $db_pass );
        if (!$conn) 
        {
            exit("Connection could not be established.");
        }

        $query = "SELECT * FROM DBA.db_table ".
            "WHERE text_val LIKE '".$aint_nr."'";

        $result = odbc_exec($conn, $query);
        if (!$result) 
        {
            odbc_close($conn);
            $response_array['status'] = "error";
            $response_array['message'] = "Failure ".$query; 
            $response_array['aint_id'] = 0;
            exit(json_encode($response_array));
        }

        odbc_fetch_row($result)
        $response_array.['status'] = 'success';
        $response_array.['message'] = 'Found: '.odbc_result($result, 2);  //<<<<<< line 58
        $response_array.['aint_id'] = odbc_result($result, 1);
        odbc_close($conn);

        echo json_encode($response_array);
    }
?>
```

Now I get an error in the PHP error log file:

```
[01-Sep-2015 07:19:51 Europe/Paris] PHP Parse error:  
    syntax error, unexpected '$response_array' (T_VARIABLE) in 
    C:\wamp\www\Concepts\get_ta_top_row.php on line 58
```

(I have marked line 58 in the above code)

I have also just noticed another error in the log:

```
[01-Sep-2015 04:06:16 UTC] PHP Warning:  
    PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
    'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - 
    Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
    in Unknown on line 0

[01-Sep-2015 04:06:16 UTC] PHP Warning:  
    PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
    'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - 
    Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
    in Unknown on line 0
```

Not sure if this has anything to do with the above error.

Any Ideas? Is it my syntax? Is it the missing dlls? So far php seems very tempermental, maybe its just that I'm used to very different languages?

Comment: Use `.` to concatenate strings in php. You're using `+=` in the first code snippet

Comment: Two lines above the one you marked isn't closed. `odbc_fetch_row($result)` should have a `;` at the end.

Comment: @LinkinTED, sorry that was a typo when formatting.

Comment: @Tushar What do you mean? I have. and it was working fine the way its written until I moved it to an external file.

Comment: Just to inform, first line of your code `<? php` acts same as `<? echo 'php';` because of the space before the word "php". Use `<?php` or `<?` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why using `$response_array.['message']`, `.` for array. Use it without `.`

```
$response_array['message'] = 'Found: '.odbc_result($result, 2);  //<<<<<< line 58
```